# Using “OR” statements in case of check the words if matching with row content in Python 2.7

Tags: python, pandas

faq:

`g3650 = "gerund_verb"
g3660 = "linking_verb"
g3670 = "auxiliary_verb"`

what's inside them? They consist of words like am, is, are, was, were etc.
what is my intention? I want to have a way to check multiple steps if the word is a gerund verb or a linking verb if it is avail to any individual row then check the next word as the same way.
what problem I am in now? When I input a word which contains in anyone of the raw; it prints found it and when I input any word out of the availability, it still shows found it.
I've tried checking other posts here but even though the question looks similar I really couldn't found the understandable answer from my level.

Here's my code:

```
df4 = pd.read_sql('select * from VERB',connection)
df5 = pd.read_sql('select * from ADVERB',connection)

df = pd.concat([df4,df5])

def word_list(text):
return list(filter(None, re.split('\W+', text)))

session = raw_input("Hi!")
feedback = session

dff = pd.DataFrame({'Sentence':[feedback]})
dff['1'] = dff['Sentence'].astype(str).str.split().str[0]
dff['2'] = dff['Sentence'].astype(str).str.split().str[1]
dff['3'] = dff['Sentence'].astype(str).str.split().str[2]

for pts1 in dff['1']:
 pts1 = df.columns[df.isin([pts1]).any()]
for pts2 in dff['2']:
 pts2 = df.columns[df.isin([pts2]).any()]
for pts3 in dff['3']:
 pts3 = df.columns[df.isin([pts3]).any()]

word_count = len(feedback.split())

g3650 = "gerund_verb"
g3660 = "linking_verb"
g3670 = "auxiliary_verb"

if word_count == 1:
 if pts1 == g3670 or g3660:
  print "found it"
```

Comment: Please pick your tags more sensibly. Most of them were irrelevant.

Comment: Seems like you want `if pts1 == g3670 or pts1 == g3660:`

Comment: Works like Charm, Man! Cool! Great You Are! :) @ user3386109

Comment: @ coldspeed :D I'll; from the next time! :)